# Formating Date time field in excell to import via data loader

Tags: data-loader, datetime, import

I  have a custom date/Time field in salesforce for a object and i am trying insert values for that field through the data loader.I have used yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss date format in excell. User time zone and company default time zones are same.But when i insert data to that field it's showing date as data as given date -1 day.This is the sample data [image]

But in salesforce it is stored as [image] and  [image]

What should i do to store the exact date from excell?

[image]

Comment: yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ

Answer (score 8):

You want to format it as:

> yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ

Where you can just make hh:mm:ss be 00:00:00.

e.g.  2016-01-18T00:00:00Z

Comment: HI Nick,Thanks for your response .I tried your format but still same result

Comment: I believe Data Loader is just looking for SQL-formatted datetimes. Tried a bunch of formats, but that's the only one that didn't throw parsing errors. For example, today would be `2020-10-08 18:57:48`.

Comment: Format the 'Date' and 'Date Time' data in a CSV file For Salesforce Data Loader - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385167&type=1

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of Excel don't have date-time formats available in the standard pick lists, but you can just enter a custom format string such as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss by:

Right click -> Format Cells
Number tab
Choose Category Custom
Enter your custom format string into the "Type" field
This works on my Excel 2010

Comment: I get the correct format in excell but when i insert data it goes one day behind.

Comment: have you checked Language & Time Zone of your salesforce org. just go through your name --> setting--> personal-->Language & Time Zone

Comment: I have posted that in my question.Is is something i should do with time zone?

Comment: Sorry my mistake... Just put this time zone (GMT-07:00) Pacific Daylight Time (America/Los_Angeles). hope so its work

Answer (score 1):

Two things about loading date types:

1. Data loader ignores the HH:MM:SS portion of Date types, so you can just write it as YYYY-MM-DD. Reserve the HH:MM:SS for Datetime types.
2. Data loader interprets all dates as GMT. When you look at it in the UI, you are looking at the local time which is MT(GMT-6).

Date '2016-01-18' in the CSV, after the load it becomes '01/17/2016 18:00:00' in the UI.

Answer (score -1):

Data import wizard requires Datetime to be in "**mm/dd/yyyy H:MM AM/PM**" format.

Also make sure that timezone set for your org is same as your machine's.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this claim?

Comment: This link lists acceptable formats, but unfortunately none of them worked for me,https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004680&language=en_US

Comment: Then I came across this link [Datetime class]( https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm), check the parse method.